# Do-So Tests for VPs and PPs

Tags: syntax, verbs

How will a Do-So test help in identifying if a PP is an adjunct or complement to the verb? Example : I ran to work. I need two pieces of evidence to prove the status of PP in a sentence.

Answer (score 5):

Recall that in English, adjunction is believed to look like this:

[image: Syntax tree \VP \V' \V' \V ran\ \ \PP to work\ \ \]

If the lower V' is a constituent, then we should expect it to be substitutable by 'do so' in the standard test, but we can't say that:

> #I did so to work. (meaning 'I ran to work')

By contrast, you can substitute the whole thing 'ran to work' with do-so:

> I went to work on Thursday.
>
> I did so on Thursday.

This suggests that 'on Thursday' is an adjunct and 'to work' is the complement, i.e. this structure is appropriate:

[image: The other tree]

Comment: Caution: Identification of adverbial phrases is ambiguous (unless marked by a comma).  I ran, [in order] to work [out].  I worked on Thursday['s edition of the newspaper].

Comment: @amI  But if the meaning's evident then the structure is not ambiguous.

Comment: Many grammarians use "licensing" to determine whether an element is a complement or an adjunct/modifier. Essentially, an element has to be "licensed" by an appropriate head to qualify as a complement.

Comment: @BillJ I agree that's a useful test, but the OP asked for do-so, so I... *lowers glasses* did so.

Comment: The 'do-so' test merely shifts the tense to an auxiliary and replaces the verb with a pronoun (so, it, that, ...).  It is only good for identifying the direct object, since we only expect un-case-marked objects after an actual verb.  Thus 'I ate the cake' becomes 'I did so to the cake'.  "I did so to work" is not ungrammatical; it is merely clunky because 'to' is poly-semantic.